# How to specify or override TypeScript config in Deno

Tags: deno

I'm starting out on a new Deno project and ran into errors

```js
const users = [
  { name: 'Oby', age: 12 },
  { name: 'Heera', age: 32 },
];

const loggedInUser = users.find((u) => u.name === 'Oby');
console.log(loggedInUser.age);
```

```
$ deno run hello.ts
Compile file:///Users/yangshun/Downloads/deno-test/hello.ts
error: TS2532 [ERROR]: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
console.log(loggedInUser.age);
```

This is caused by `"strictNullChecks": true` in the TypeScript config. Hence I would like to use my own `tsconfig.json` (TypeScript configuration) but am not sure how to go about doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create a `tsconfig.json` file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "strictNullChecks": false
  }
}
```

2. Execute the `deno run` with the `-c` configuration argument.

```sh
$ deno run -c tsconfig.json hello.ts
Compile file:///Users/yangshun/Downloads/deno-test/hello.ts
12
```